# Half encrypted?

Tags: lvm, encryption

My Volume Group has 2 physical volumes, one is created long ago and has been encrypted, but another is not. Can some files on this LVM be accessed without password?

(formatting reconstructed)

```
root@ubuntu:~# pvdisplay -m

WARNING: Device for PV 6o4ePR-GeDC-1ZTO-26Gt-tfzv-cbJb-kLjFC4 not found or rejected by a filter. 
--- Physical volume --- 
PV Name unknown device 
VG Name omyvg 
PV Size 196.00 MiB / not usable 4.00 MiB 
Allocatable yes (but full) 
PE Size 4.00 MiB 
Total PE 48 
Free PE 0 
Allocated PE 48 
PV UUID 6o4ePR-GeDC-1ZTO-26Gt-tfzv-cbJb-kLjFC4

--- Physical Segments --- 
Physical extent 0 to 38:  
Logical volume /dev/omyvg/datA 
Logical extents 0 to 38 

Physical extent 39 to 45: 
Logical volume /dev/omyvg/datB 
Logical extents 0 to 6

Physical extent 46 to 47: 
Logical volume /dev/omyvg/MEm 
Logical extents 0 to 1

--- Physical volume --- 
PV Name /dev/sda1 
VG Name omyvg 
PV Size 66.00 MiB / not usable 2.00 MiB 
Allocatable yes 
PE Size 4.00 MiB 
Total PE 16 
Free PE 10 
Allocated PE 6 
PV UUID vmkKDN-n0pW-D9Pi-WN8m-8Isc-lAWq-mU0mBq

--- Physical Segments --- 
Physical extent 0 to 5: 
Logical volume /dev/omyvg/datB 
Logical extents 7 to 12 

Physical extent 6 to 15: FREE

"/dev/sda4" is a new physical volume of "93.00 MiB" 
--- NEW Physical volume --- 
PV Name /dev/sda4 
VG Name 
PV Size 93.00 MiB 
Allocatable NO 
PE Size 0 
Total PE 0 
Free PE 0 
Allocated PE 0 
PV UUID MuZCwu-jpWR-bI2U-Jq2U-S1Tt-XRXE-ZaX3ne

"/dev/sda3" is a new physical volume of "43.00 MiB" 
--- NEW Physical volume --- 
PV Name /dev/sda3 
VG Name 
PV Size 43.00 MiB 
Allocatable NO 
PE Size 0 
Total PE 0 
Free PE 0 
Allocated PE 0 
PV UUID l4Q4gf-pHzT-7o41-Myl3-sgpW-aSa1-rb4Cv4
```

(formatting reconstructed)

```
root@ubuntu:~# pvs -v --segments 

Using physical volume(s) on command line. 
WARNING: Device for PV 6o4ePR-GeDC-1ZTO-26Gt-tfzv-cbJb-kLjFC4 not found or rejected by a filter. 
There are 1 physical volumes missing. 
There are 1 physical volumes missing. 
PV        VG    Fmt  Attr PSize  PFree  Start SSize LV   Start Type   PE Ranges 
/dev/sda1 omyvg lvm2 a--  64.00m 40.00m 0     6     datB 7     linear /dev/sda1:0-5  
/dev/sda1 omyvg lvm2 a--  64.00m 40.00m 6     10         0     free 
/dev/sda3       lvm2 ---  43.00m 43.00m 0     0          0     free 
/dev/sda4       lvm2 ---  93.00m 93.00m 0     0          0     free

PV             VG    Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree  Start SSize  LV   Start Type   PE Ranges 
unknown device omyvg lvm2 a-m  192.00m 0      0     39     datA 0     linear unknown device:0-38 
unknown device omyvg lvm2 a-m  192.00m 0     39      7     datB 0     linear unknown device:39-45 
unknown device omyvg lvm2 a-m  192.00m 0     46      2     MEm  0     linear unknown device:46-47
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how the logical volumes are laid out on the physical volumes. The output of `pvdisplay -m` or `pvs -v --segments` would be very helpful in determining which LVs might be accessible.

If any LVs are wholly contained in the unencrypted PV, then you should be able to activate them and then mount them as normal.

```
lvchange -ay <LV device pathname> 
mount <LV device pathname> <mountpoint>
```

If a LV has only its tail end (highest-numbered extents) contained in the encrypted PV, you might try and activate the LV with

```
lvchange -ay --activationmode partial <LV device pathname>
```

You could then mount the filesystem as read-only and hopefully read files from the non-encrypted part. Attempting to read a file that is partly or fully within the encrypted zone would probably result in an error message and/or a truncated file.

If a LV has its beginning (lowest-numbered extents) contained in the encrypted PV, it is likely the filesystem cannot be easily mounted, as important filesystem metadata often tends to be located towards the beginning of the filesystem. Filesystem-specific recovery tools might still be able to recover some files from the un-encrypted portion.

(Update:)
From the command outputs, I can see that:

- `/dev/omyvg/datA` LV is completely on the missing (encrypted) device
- `/dev/omyvg/datB` has its first 7 extents (28 MB, more than half) on the missing device
- `/dev/omyvg/MEm` is completely on the missing device

You might try

```
lvchange -ay --activationmode partial /dev/omyvg/datB
```

but since the first half of the LV is missing, you won't able to just mount it. If you know this LV contains an ext2/3/4 type filesystem, you might be able to locate a copy of the filesystem superblock in the surviving area, and use it to recover something... or just use some file recovery tools that read through the LV and try and identify any files they come across.

Of course, if you know that `/dev/omyvg/datB` was never more than 50% used, you might find that all that is accessible is just unused space :-(

Comment: Thank you! my network has problem for weeks, here is my output, which one is the one can recover?

Comment: which one is the one can recover?

Comment: --- Physical volume ---
PV Name /dev/sda1
VG Name omyvg
PV Size 66.00 MiB / not usable 2.00 MiB
Allocatable yes 
PE Size 4.00 MiB
Total PE 16
Free PE 10
Allocated PE 6
PV UUID vmkKDN-n0pW-D9Pi-WN8m-8Isc-lAWq-mU0mBq

--- Physical Segments ---
Physical extent 0 to 5:
Logical volume /dev/omyvg/datB
Logical extents 7 to 12
Physical extent 6 to 15:
FREE

Is this the reason  some part of Logical volume /dev/omyvg/datB is in the PV Name /dev/sda1?

Comment: You can also select text and press CTRL+K to toggle indenting as code.<br/>I have done it before  clicking on Add Comment

Comment: The output you pasted into your second-latest comment does indicate that the second part (almost a half) of LV /dev/omyvg/datB is located in PV sda1. The reason why it's there cannot be determined for certain, but I can guess: at some point, the VG included more than one PV, and when the LV was created, it was allocated wherever there was free space. That's one of the big points of LVM: you can extend your filesystems beyond any single disk.But as you discovered, it would be good if all the PVs in a VG had similar properties.

Comment: Thank you 4 reading  my un-formatted  comments, it's not easy, goodman.

Answer (score 0):

```
'root@ubuntu:~# pvdisplay -m
```

WARNING: Device for PV 6o4ePR-GeDC-1ZTO-26Gt-tfzv-cbJb-kLjFC4 not found or rejected by a filter.
--- Physical volume ---
PV Name unknown device
VG Name omyvg
PV Size 196.00 MiB / not usable 4.00 MiB
Allocatable yes (but full)
PE Size 4.00 MiB
Total PE 48
Free PE 0
Allocated PE 48
PV UUID 6o4ePR-GeDC-1ZTO-26Gt-tfzv-cbJb-kLjFC4

--- Physical Segments ---
Physical extent 0 to 38:
Logical volume /dev/omyvg/datA
Logical extents 0 to 38
Physical extent 39 to 45:
Logical volume /dev/omyvg/datB
Logical extents 0 to 6
Physical extent 46 to 47:
Logical volume /dev/omyvg/MEm
Logical extents 0 to 1

--- Physical volume ---
PV Name /dev/sda1
VG Name omyvg
PV Size 66.00 MiB / not usable 2.00 MiB
Allocatable yes 
PE Size 4.00 MiB
Total PE 16
Free PE 10
Allocated PE 6
PV UUID vmkKDN-n0pW-D9Pi-WN8m-8Isc-lAWq-mU0mBq

--- Physical Segments ---
Physical extent 0 to 5:
Logical volume /dev/omyvg/datB
Logical extents 7 to 12
Physical extent 6 to 15:
FREE

"/dev/sda4" is a new physical volume of "93.00 MiB"
--- NEW Physical volume ---
PV Name /dev/sda4
VG Name 
PV Size 93.00 MiB
Allocatable NO
PE Size 0 
Total PE 0
Free PE 0
Allocated PE 0
PV UUID MuZCwu-jpWR-bI2U-Jq2U-S1Tt-XRXE-ZaX3ne

"/dev/sda3" is a new physical volume of "43.00 MiB"
--- NEW Physical volume ---
PV Name /dev/sda3
VG Name 
PV Size 43.00 MiB
Allocatable NO
PE Size 0 
Total PE 0
Free PE 0
Allocated PE 0
PV UUID l4Q4gf-pHzT-7o41-Myl3-sgpW-aSa1-rb4Cv4

```
root@ubuntu:~# pvs -v --segments
```

Using physical volume(s) on command line.
WARNING: Device for PV 6o4ePR-GeDC-1ZTO-26Gt-tfzv-cbJb-kLjFC4 not found or rejected by a filter.
There are 1 physical volumes missing.
There are 1 physical volumes missing.
PV VG Fmt Attr PSize PFree Start SSize LV Start Type PE Ranges 
/dev/sda1 omyvg lvm2 a-- 64.00m 40.00m 0 6 datB 7 linear /dev/sda1:0-5 
/dev/sda1 omyvg lvm2 a-- 64.00m 40.00m 6 10 0 free 
/dev/sda3 lvm2 --- 43.00m 43.00m 0 0 0 free 
/dev/sda4 lvm2 --- 93.00m 93.00m 0 0 0 free 
unknown device omyvg lvm2 a-m 192.00m 0 0 39 datA 0 linear unknown device:0-38 
unknown device omyvg lvm2 a-m 192.00m 0 39 7 datB 0 linear unknown device:39-45
unknown device omyvg lvm2 a-m 192.00m 0 46 2 MEm 0 linear unknown device:46-47'

Comment: Sorry, I don,t know how to create right formatted reply. When I paste the output here, it getsa  wrong formatted.

Comment: I edited them into your original question for you, salvaging the formatting. Now let me think a bit...

Comment: I updated my answer.